# jQuery each: run through each set of a li individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I don't even know how to explain my problem - that's where the weird title comes from.
I have a `ul` wrapping another `ul` like the sample underneath.

```
<ul class="event-items">
   <li class="year 2012"></li>
   <li class="year 2011"></li>
   <li class="year 2010">
      <ul>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
<li class="year 2010"></li>
…
```

[image]

So each `li.year` has another `<ul>` with multiple children inside.

**Now my problem:**

I wonder how I can run through `each` `li.year` individually.

Right now I'm doing this …

```
$('ul.event-items li.year ul li').each(function(i) {
    if ( i % 4 == 0 ) $(this).addClass('clearLeft');
});
```

However this `each` loop runs through a ALL `<li>`s. I wonder how I can run through each `li:year li` individually. Sounds weird right?

So I actually want to loop through each of `li.year` individually so that my `i` count always starts fresh inside each `li.year`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use nested loops to iterate over the children of each inner `ul` separately:

```
$('ul.event-items li.year ul').each(function() {
    $("li", this).each(function(i) {
        if (i % 4 == 0) 
            $(this).addClass('clearLeft');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
$('ul.event-items li.year').each(function(i) {
    if ( i % 4 == 0 ) $(this).find('ul li').addClass('clearLeft');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

```
$('ul.event-items li.year ul li').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ( $this.index() % 4 == 0 ) $this.addClass('clearLeft');
});
```

`.index()` will return you the index of each `li` in relation to its parent, `ul`.